# Trying to split strings into multiple parts with Python

Tags: python, unicode, split

I am trying to split a string in the following manner. Here is a sample strings:

```
"Hello this is a string.-2.34 This is an example1 string."
```

Please note that "" is a U+F8FF unicode character and the type of the string is Unicode.

I want to break the string as:

```
"Hello this is a string.","-2.34"," This is an example1 string."
```

I have written a regex to split the string but using this I cannot get the numeric part that I want. (-2.34 in first string)

My code:

```
import re
import os
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str, smart_unicode

text = open(r"C:\data.txt").read()
text = text.decode('utf-8')
print(smart_str(text))

pat = re.compile(u"\uf8ff-*\d+\.*\d+")
newpart = pat.split(text)
firstpart = newpart[::1]

print ("first part of the string ----")
for f in firstpart:
f = smart_str(f)
print ("-----")
print f
```

---

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put parentheses around `-*\d+\.*\d+` if you want to keep it in the result of `re.split`:

```
import re
text = u"Hello this is a string.\uf8ff-2.34 This is an example1 string."
print(re.split(u'\uf8ff(-*\d+\.*\d+)', text))
```

yields

```
[u'Hello this is a string.', u'-2.34', u' This is an example1 string.']
```